# English-language equivalent to the Russian idiom, 'Not let someone within firing distance near X'

Tags: expressions, idioms

I've been hard put to come up with the most appropriate English expression for a particular Russian one.

In Russian, an expression that roughly translates as "To not let someone come near X within a firing distance" is fairly common. I believe it's self-explanatory, so I won't going into much detail here. But here's an example of it in use:

> This guy shouldn't be allowed within a firing distance near children.

What would be the best "native" English expression to convey the same idea?

Comment: *Within firing distance* is also an English idiom.

Comment: "anywhere near"

Answer (score 9):

We have the saying "within spitting distance".

*. This guy shouldn't be allowed within spitting distance of X.*

> within spitting distance
>
> =  close, near, beside, alongside, close by, just round the corner, within sniffing distance (informal), a hop, skip and a jump away
>   (informal) • a restaurant within spitting distance of the Tower of
>   London
>
> http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/within-spitting-distance

I'm not sure it's the best option for your specific example.

Another possibility is "within a mile of".

. ***This guy shouldn't be allowed within a mile of children.***

This doesn't literally mean a mile, just a long distance.

Comment: A mile is probably closer to actual firing distance than spitting distance is; I think I'd go with that here.

Comment: I don't think the first one really works, spitting distance is used to suggest closeness, but the implication of the original phrase is that the person should be kept at a considerable distance.

Comment: Oh, and I think for the second one, a _country_ mile could be used as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a phrase *[I wouldn't touch it [him/her] with a ten foot pole](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/not+touch+with+a+ten-foot+pole)*

> (verb phrase)
>
> To be loath to have anything to do with; be suspicious or apprehensive; reject : *If I were you I wouldn't touch that proposition with a ten-foot pole*
>
> [1909+; semantically akin to the proverb advising us to use a long spoon when we eat with the devil; an earlier and once more common version spoke of a forty-foot pole]

*Dictionary.com*

This phrase is sometimes applied to potential (or not so potential) romantic partners.

If you are specifically looking for the dangerous aspect, this doesn't supply it.

**Supplement**

Another phrase concerning keeping one's distance is *I would [avoid him [it/her] like the plague](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/avoid+like+the+plague)*

> Evade or elude at any cost, shun. For example, *Since Bob was taken into police custody, his friends have been avoiding him and his family like the plague.*
>
> This seemingly modern expression dates from the Latin of the early Middle Ages, when Saint Jerome (a.d. 345-420) wrote, "Avoid, as you would the plague, a clergyman who is also a man of business." The plague, a deadly infectious disease in his day, has been largely wiped out, but the term remains current.

*American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* found at idioms.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: “He shouldn't be allowed to touch children with a ten-inch pole” sounds just a tad _wrong_, though…

Comment: Shame on you!  Oh, maybe you meant a ten-inch Pole. But it's not nice to joke about height-challenged Slavs either.

Answer (score 3):

A man or woman of this variety should be **kept at arms length**... this is a bit closer than a 10 foot pole and a little further than spitting distance; you might also say within **a stones throw**, a distance very similar to spitting distance. It's all about distance and the understanding that coming closer might cause a violent action.

Comment: But firing distance add a hint what to do if person come closer. So stone trow is closest answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Then it seems like within a stones throw would be the most appropriate phrase for you. I will edit my answer to reflect that notion

Answer (score 1):

One way to express it ( because of a restraining  order for instance ) is to to say that someone is:

> - Not allowed to be within 100 feet/yards of someone or something